# unable to display radio button group in angular js dynamic form

Tags: angularjs

what is the simplest way to display a radio button and dropdown list using templating in angular js? I have a plunker where i'd like to display the radio button group(quest#4) options as dynamic values - i am not sure how to do so. I am having the same issue with the selects(quest#5) as well. Any help is much appreciated.

http://run.plnkr.co/eHxbQn2lm1uTE2JI/

Comment: could you provide a link to a plunkr that shows you code?

Comment: hi Ed, i thought i did, anyway here goes. I figured out the radio button group . still stuck on the select group though.:http://plnkr.co/edit/YMM1G6sE60G8LHAU4SMs?p=info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't see your attempt at using a `<select>` in your code, so here's an abstracted example, if you had the choices like so:

```
.controller('AppControl', ($scope)->
  $scope.answers = 
    q1: null
    q2: null

  $scope.options = {
    "option 1": "val1",
    "option 2": "val2"
  }
)
```

Then you could make a radio button list would look like this:

```
<span ng-repeat="(key, value) in options">
  <input type="radio" ng-model="answers.q1" ng-value="value"/> {{key}}
</span>
```

And a select would look like this:

```
<select ng-model="answers.q2" 
        ng-options="value as key for (key, value) in options">
</select>
```

**EDIT**

To answer the second part of your question below: "how do I use ng-show in this case?":

To do this, you need to add the possibility of having a "show if" type condition in your questions. If there is a condition, then you only want to show the question if that condition is met. Your HTML for each question would change to look like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="question in questionnaire" 
     ng-include="'questionnaire'" 
     ng-show="(question.condition == null) || {{question.condition}}"></div>
```

Note that you check whether a condition has been specified, and if it hasn't, then the `ng-show` expression would evaluate to true. If it has, we interpolate that condition so that we can use the same syntax as we would for other `ng-show`s.

You then just need to adjust your question to include a condition, for example:

```
{ 
   number: "5", 
   question: "Which of the following sweets do you like?", 
   type: "DD", 
   condition: 'questionnaire[$index-1].answer != "blue"',
   values :[
     { name: "hardcandy" },
     { name: "chocolate" },
     { name: "other" },
   ]
}
```

`questionnaire[$index-1]` refers to the previous question (`$index` is from `ng-repeat`, check the docs), and `.answer` only works because I have used `ng-model="question.answer"` when I answered your previous query. I would personally add this `ng-model` attribute to all of your questions.

You can see it working here: [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/p5c0h4TCqoVYvRCjQu1j?p=preview)

Comment: i appreciate your help. My controller however looks a bit different. It takes shape of nodes. were you able to view the plunker?

Comment: I just had a look now.. here's the approach you've used working: http://plnkr.co/edit/p5c0h4TCqoVYvRCjQu1j?p=preview

Comment: how would i implement hideshow in my case. I.e if i select 'blue' I would want to hide the dropdown. any ideas?

Comment: That's another question entirely really... I'll edit my answer as it won't fit in a comment..

Comment: i'll ad a new question